# Angular 4 different menu options based on link click in dashboard page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-routing

I am new to Angular 2 and i am struggling to create a sample project  structure with below requirement and searching in google for proper link.

I have done my step 1 and step 2 but step 3 is confusing (May be this concept related to routing between different modules)

Does any help me,

Below is the Requirement.

step 1: Login page.
Step 2: After successful login user should naviagate to a page which consists of three links.

so user can click any one of link in this page.

Step 3: and for each link click user should navigate to a another page which consists of navigation menu of links related to particular link in second step.

So here again user can click any one of links and after clck relative html page should displayed.

Comment: so you want to create a web app , what searches u tried please list

Comment: I have done my step 1 and step 2 but step 3 is confusing (May be this concept related to routing between different modules)

Comment: you need to pass info via routing use using pathparms in angular or use query parms or shared services to pass info between routes this should be a good starting point

Comment: Can you do a tree to better understand your problem: like this: https://d33wubrfki0l68.cloudfront.net/36507fe062ad1e57d6fabdb24b56a663cb7d0973/51ccb/images/angular/augury/augury-router-tree.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you just want nested routes.

you can have:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path: 'pages',
    loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
  }, {
    path: 'login',
    component: loginComponent,
 }
]
```

loadChildren is there to do lazy-loading

the route of your PagesModule:

```
const routes : Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: PagesComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'whatever',
            component: WhateverComponent
          }, {
            path: 'morewhatever',
            component: MoreWhateverComponent
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Comment: Thanks.. i will try with given example provided but how to navigate to these child component when clicking on a link..

Comment: import router and then:  this.router.navigate(['/pages/dashboard']); 
You can read all about router here: https://angular.io/guide/router